# LG Optimus Pro C660 won't vibrate for SMS

Tags: notifications, vibration

I just bought the Optimus Pro C660 and it will vibrate when I get a call or the alarm clock goes off but it won't vibrate when receiving an SMS. I have gone through all the settings and set it to "Vibrate Always", but it still doesn't work. I heard that you can download apps to make it vibrate - would that help? Are there any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Messaging. Select setting. Go to notification settings. There you have an option to switch on vibration for Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go with a 3rd party app, I'd recommend [Handcent SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms). It goes a step further by allowing you to assign specific vibration patterns to different contacts.